# Docker Compose USB Mount

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to mount my USB drive to a docker container but running into some issues.

The USB drive auto mounts via /etc/fstab and is chown'd to pi:pi with perms of 777 across the board. So there shouldn't be a true permissions issue.

Within my docker-compose.yml, I have the following:

```
plex:
 image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/plex/bionic
 container_name: plex
 network_mode: host
 environment:
  - PUID=1000
  - PGID=1000
  - VERSION=docker
  - UMASK_SET=022
 volumes:
  - ./volumes/plex/library:/config
  - /media:/media
 restart: unless-stopped
```

It's the /media:/media line that doesn't seem to be working. If I get a bash shell inside of the container I'm not seeing any of the files I expect to see.

I'm a docker noob but have tried reading a lot of forums and haven't had much luck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I'm using "docker-compose restart" when bringing up my various containers after making changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I literally found the issue right after I posted this.

I thought "docker-compose restart" forced a re-read of the file but it does not. I had to do "docker-compose up -d" for it to reread the file and then it worked.